# Using the replace function in firestore security rules

Tags: firebase, replace, firebase-security, rules, google-cloud-firestore

I'm struggling with Firestore security rules. I want to check on a value that needs the replace function, i.e. an e-mail address. I can find some documentation in the general security docs, but that does not seem to work with Firestore.

For example this works:

```
allow write: if resource.data.members.data[(request.auth.token.email)] in ["admin"];
```

but this doesn't (and I changed the key in the members object accordingly):

```
allow write: if resource.data.members.data[(request.auth.token.email.replace('.' , ',')] in ["admin"];
```

Another option would be to have a way to use dots in the address of a query, so they don't have to be replaced like this:

```
var emailSanitized = email.replace('.' , '.');
db.collection('someCollection').where('members.' + emailSanitized, '==', 'admin')
```

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 3):

A little late, but you can simulate the replace function on a string with this one :

```
function replace(string, replace, by) {
  return string.split(replace).join(by);
}
```

So you need to define this function in your firestore.rules file and then you can call `replace(request.auth.token.email, '.' , ',')` to get the same result as `request.auth.token.email.replace('.' , ',')` in javascript.

Answer (score 3):

There are two reasons why you might have been having issues.

1. The `replace` function was added to Security Rules after you asked your question.
2. The `replace` function uses regular expressions for the first argument and so matching on `'.'` will match literally everything.

Consider instead using: `request.auth.token.email.replace('\\.' , ',')`

Answer (score 0):

var emailSanitized = email.replace('.' , '.');
db.collection('someCollection').where('members.' + emailSanitized, '==', 'admin')

Comment: Please add more than just code.  Explain why your answer is correct.

Comment: I can see I made a typo with the dot replace by a dot in this code, but the second actually is a comma.

Comment: I got a response from the Firestore support and the Replace function isn't supported yet in Firestore.