# Firestore security rule split join method not working as expected

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am facing two problems:

- You can't change the period '.' character in 'firebase rules' when you are using something like 'request.auth.token.email' (very limited options to manipulate strings and join,replace functions are not supported)
- You can't use email in your query because of the same period character as a 'key' if using hashmap.

Giving up on HashMap approach because of problems above, I am trying to explore Arrays. Is there any way to get the logged in user's email by request.auth.token.email and compare it to the 'email' elements of an array in the document?

For example - I have 'bb@gmail.com' as a logged in user, I would like to get all the documents where 'sharedWith' array contains 'bb@gmail.com' as an entry and ignore the rest of the documents. I can achieve it in the code but I want to set up this arrangement as a 'security rule' as well to make reading the document more robust.

---------Update-----------
I tried the split and join in my security rule as below:
(ref: [Using the replace function in firestore security rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47070823/using-the-replace-function-in-firestore-security-rules))

> ```
>   allow read: if isSignedIn() && resource.data.sharedWith[(request.auth.token.email).split('.').join(',')] in ["true"];
> ```

My query is as follows:

```
db.collection("Sites")
        .whereEqualTo("sharedWith.bb@gmail,com","true")
```

My document has the following:

```
sharedWith
     mm@gmail,com : "true"
     bb@gmail,com : "true"
```

And the user is logged in as 'bb@gmail.com'

The above setup is not working. I am getting permission denied error.
I don't know what am I doing wrong, help please.

Answer (score 0):

Your document structure looks like a map, but you're treating it like an array.  You can't do that.  You can only perform array operations on array type fields.  If you have an object type field, an array operation will fail on it, and your rule will immediately reject access.

If you want to check if there's a property of an object field with the value true (and you should use a boolean value, not a string), then check for existence on that object.  An object type field in Firestore is a [Map](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map) object is rules, you can get the value of that property using square brackets.

```
resource.data.sharedWith[request.auth.token.email.split('.').join(',')];
```

That expression should evaluate to true if the modified string is present and true.

Again, don't use the string value of "true", which is different than the more appropriate boolean value `true`.

Comment: I changed the map values to boolean and my query to: .whereEqualTo("sharedWith."+"bb@gmail,com",true). I then changed my security rule to be - allow read: if isSignedIn() && resource.data.sharedWith[request.auth.token.email.split('.').join(',')]; Unfortunately no luck after these boolean changes. Permission is still getting denied @DougStevenson

Comment: Are you testing your rules in the console using the request simulator? It should give you more information.  Even better, use the emulator to test a scenario with more diagnostics.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator

Answer (score 0):

`split` takes a regex as a parameter so `.` will match literally any character.

Apart from fixing that you could replace this with the replace function for strings:

```
allow read: if isSignedIn() && resource.data.sharedWith[(request.auth.token.email).replace('\\.', ',')] in ["true"];
```